# How to approach this variant of NIM game?

Tags: game-theory

Recently i came across a problem which gives you a 4*4 matrix consisting of only 0's and 1's. 2 players are playing the game,In each turn a player can select any submatrix consisting of only 1's and make it 0.The player who is unable to move loses.How to apply sprague grundy theorem in this?

EXAMPLE-
0110
0000
0000
0001

Then player 1 will win(will remove one "1" in first row in first turn,in 2nd turn player 2 will take one 1,& thus p1 takes the final 1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply the Sprague-Grundy theorem here. The theorem is used whenever you play multiple games, like for instance you play two games on two boards.

You can simply decide if the board is a winning or loosing state if you apply the usually recursive definitions: A board is in a winning state, if at least one move leads to a loosing state. And a board is in a loosing state, if no move leads to a loosing state.

```
def is_winning_state(board):
    for each rectangle rect of 1s on the board:
        if not is_winning_state(board - rect):
             return True
    return false
```

You also want to apply dynamic programming, otherwise the program will not finish in a reasonable time.